# Ruby on Rails validation on input form generating errors

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, haml

My Tracks model has an integer column called 'bpm'

When I try to submit the form to create a new track and add it to the database; the following error occurs:

`Field can't be blank`

This occurs despite the field being filled in and the validations surrounding it have been carried out, perhaps there's an error in the post request?

The post-request functions correctly when I do not validate the bpm field.

views > tracks > _form.html.haml

```
.columns
  .column.is-8.is-centered
    = simple_form_for @track, html: { multipart: true } do |f|
      = f.error_notification
      .columns
        .field.column.is-9
          .control
            = f.input :name , required: true, input_html: { class: "input"}, wrapper: false, label_html: { class:"label" }
        .field.column
          .control
            = f.input :price, required: true, input_html: { class:"input", maxlength: 7  }, wrapper: false, label_html: { class:"label" }
        .field.column
          .control
            = f.input :bpm, required: true, input_html: {class:"input", maxlength: 3}, wrapper: false, label_html: { class:"label" }
      .field
        .control
          = f.input :description, required: true, input_html: { class:"textarea" }, wrapper: false, label_html: { class:"label" }
      .columns
        .field.column.is-4
          .control
            %label.label Genre
            .control.has-icons-left
              %span.select
                = f.input_field :genre, collection: Track::GENRE, prompt: "Select type"
              %span.icon.is-small.is-left
                %i.fa.fa-tag
      .field
        .control
          %label.label Add images
          .file
            %label.file-label
              = f.input :image, as: :file, input_html: { class:"file-input track-image" }, label: false, wrapper: false
              %span.file-cta
                %span.file-icon
                  %i.fa.fa-upload
                %span.file-label Choose a file…
      %output#list
      %hr/
      .field.is-grouped
        .control
          = f.button :submit, class: 'button is-warning'
          = link_to 'Cancel', tracks_path, class:'button is-light'
```

models > track.rb

```
class Track < ApplicationRecord
  before_destroy :not_referenced_by_any_line_item
  belongs_to :user, optional: true
  has_many :line_items

  mount_uploader :image, ImageUploader
  serialize :image, JSON #sqlite

  validates :name, :genre, :price, :bpm, presence: true
  validates :description, length: { maximum: 1000, too_long: "Up to %{count} characters allowed"}, presence: true
  validates :bpm, length: { maximum: 3 }
  validates :price, length: { maximum: 5 }
  GENRE = %w{ Trap Hip-Hop R&B Funk Electro-R&B }


  private
  def not_referenced_by_any_line_item
    unless line_items.empty?
      errors.add(:base, "Line items present")
      throw :abort
    end
  end

end
```

track schema:

```
create_table "tracks", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "name"
    t.text "description"
    t.decimal "price", precision: 5, scale: 2, default: "0.0"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.string "image"
    t.integer "user_id"
    t.string "genre"
    t.integer "bpm"
  end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you whitelisted the parameter in `TracksController`?

```
def track_params
  params.require(:track).permit(:price, :genre, :bpm)
end
```

This is just an example

Comment: My pleasure Sir